# How to implement guava cache for a method that method declare inside interface and that interface is implemented by two different classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, guava

I have simple Guava LoadingCache use case where I have an interface which contains a method. This interface is implemented by two different classes. I need to implement Guava cache for that method

**What need to pass in CacheLoader class when i build cache.**

`public interface Operation{
  int squareOfNum(int x);

  int sumOfNum(int x);

}`

Now I have two classes that implement above interface.

```
public class A extends CacheLoader<String, Integer> implement Operation{  

   @Override
   public int squareOfNum(int x){
   // read x value from S3 Storage and return  
   return x;
   }

   @Override
   public int sumOfNum(int x){
   return x+x;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
     return squareOfNum(Integer.parseInt(key));
   }
}


public class B extends CacheLoader<String, Integer> implement Operation{

   @Override
   public int squareOfNum(int x){
    // Read x value from Mongodb and return value of x
    return x;
   }

   @Override
   public int sumOfNum(int x){
     return x+x+2;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
     return squareOfNum(Integer.parseInt(key));
   }
}
```

I also create cacheloader class:

```
public class CacheLoader {
  static final LoadingCache<String, Integer> cache_method = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .maximumSize(1000)
  .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  .build(new CacheLoader<String, Integer>() {
      public Integer load(String key) throws IOException {
         return squareOfNum(Integer.valueOf(key));
      }
   });


public Integer getSquare( int x)
{
  int y = 0;
  try {
    y = cache_method.get(String.valueOf(x));
    log.info("Size of Cache is {} ",cache_method.size());
    } catch ( ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return y;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused -- it sounds like you need two caches, not one, one with each `CacheLoader`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I need one cache.

Comment: What content do you want to be in that cache?  Do you want the result of both A and B for each input?  Do you want to only cache whichever one you use?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I want cache for input x. I think we need two cache for each method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I want cache for x which is coming from different storage. So i think it requires only one cache.

Comment: @LouisWasserman please help me for that problem